# Is there a way to run Unity without rendering the scene on the monitor (headless)?

Tags: unity, rendering, simulations

I am doing some machine learning and I get my environment from Unity in the form of images but the training is taking too long and it keeps me from doing anything else on my system. Is there a way to hide the simulation rendering?
Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Run Unity in batch mode with `-batchmode` in combination with `-executeMethod <ClassName.MethodName>` (and likely `-quit`, which quits the Editor after commands have finished executing).

For example:

```
"C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Unity.exe" -quit -batchmode -executeMethod MachineLearningTrainer.Start
```

Note `executeMethod` only works with static methods.

For more information, see [Unity's documentation on Command line arguments](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CommandLineArguments.html).